# Why does inspect say that my module is built-in?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
mod = importlib.import_module('mortgagecomparison')
inspect.getsourcefile(mod)
```

Yields:

```
TypeError: <module 'mortgagecomparison' (namespace)> is a built-in module
```

But the module is not built-in, it's made by me, then installed a `pip install -e .`.

Comment: Is it an extension module written in C or C++?

Comment: Nope, i was just lacking an init.py

Answer (score 3):

In the message:

```
module 'mortgagecomparison' (namespace)
```

indicates that this is *not* an imported module or package, just a directory name, presumably without an `__init__.py`